# Why won't my VS2012 recognize modified files on disk and reload?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've been away from Windows and Visual Studio for a few years.  Now I have VS2012, and I notice that it fails to recognize that a file has changed on disk (i.e. by a different editor).  In fact, even if I hit the refresh button on the Solution Explorer window, it still doesn't reload the file.  I can close the window and reopen it -- still no luck.  I thought "gosh, I hope I don't have to close and reopen the solution each time!", but it turns out even THAT doesn't do the trick.

Its as if VS is caching old copies of files and cannot imagine that someone might use something other than VS to modify them.

These are just local files, no network issues involved.   I must be missing an understanding of some major new "feature", yes?

--- Edit: -----
Ok, here's some progress.   I've been using the VsVim extension to have a vim-compatible keymap.   On a hunch, I disabled it, restarted VS, and found the problem solved.  Then, I re-enabled it, and the problem is still solved.    So the mystery remains, but not the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that file is being modified?  The feature to detect an external modification and reload the file is still there.  And if you close and re-open the file or even the entire IDE, it would definitely load whatever is the current content of the file.  It really sounds like the external editor either isn't saving or is modifying a different file.

Comment: Well I thought of that, so I removed the file entirely from the VS solution, and added it back in.  When I do that, it _does_ show the new content.  I've also loaded the file with several other editors, and they all agree with the new content.  Only VS seems stuck on keeping old versions somewhere.

Comment: Ok, here's some progress.   I've been using the VsVim extension to have a vim-compatible keymap.   On a hunch, I disabled it, restarted VS, and found the problem solved.  Then, I re-enabled it, and the problem is still solved.    So the mystery remains, but not the problem.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: Interesting.  I've never used that plugin, but traditionally editors like Vim do retain a separate version of the file for persistent auto-save without overwriting the actual file until explicitly told to do so, long undo chains, things like that.  Similar to the system file that Office apps make when opening a document.  So technically it probably *was* a "different file" but one that was being obscured by the plugin and probably hidden by Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking maybe the VsVim plugin's state got into a strange twist.  I have very little experience with it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have VS2012 (I went up to 2005), but from what I remember, this is configurable from the IDE. In VS2005 go to the menu, choose Tools, then Options, then Documents, then you'll see the options to detect when files are changed externally, and to auto-load files changed externally. I think in VS2012 it'll be similar.

Comment: Ok, here's some progress.   I've been using the VsVim extension to have a vim-compatible keymap.   On a hunch, I disabled it, restarted VS, and found the problem solved.  Then, I re-enabled it, and the problem is still solved.    So the mystery remains, but not the problem.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: Now that the core problem is solved, your suggestion did indeed take me to the next stage: having it auto-reload.  That option in 2012 is apparently the same in the version you recall.

Comment: In VS 2012 it's the same: Tools > Options > Environment > Documents -> "Detect when file is changed outside the environment" and "Auto-load changes, if saved" checkboxes.

Comment: Also, according to my experience, you get the warning from visual studio, if the file is actually opened in the IDE at the time when it was changed by an external editor. When it is not open (but part of the solution), then there's no reason for warning: next time you open it, you open up the changed file anyway.